# Adding menu types with custom url parameters to component in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, components

I'm having problems adding custom url parameters to my component menu. My component displays different data on the same view depending on which value from predetermined set is passed via custom GET parameter. For example, let's say these two urls are *the only* valid variants of the same view:

```
?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&option=hello
?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&option=world
```

How can I add these two urls as separate menu types to the component?

Answer (score 2):

you need to change your default.xml file in such a way that when you create menu it will ask you for the optional parameter.

The default.xml file located at **component/your_component/views/yourview/tmpl/default.xml**

The code will look like as below

```
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request">    
        <field name="option" type="hidden"
            label=""
            required=""
            description=""
            default="default-value"
        />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

For reference check **components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.xml** file

Answer (score 0):

You can use External URL.

Create a new menu and select External URL from Menu Item Type > System Links. Add your urls in the Link field.

I hope I was of any help.

Comment: That is a potential workaround, but I was hoping for a way to make them appear as menu type choices for the component like separate views would appear

Comment: Could you please post a practical example?